# C pointer array with elements of other pointer array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization

I have 2x structs, one for color (PixelColor) and the second for holding an array of available colors (Palette).

```
typedef struct{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int a;
}PixelColor;

typedef struct{
    int size;
    PixelColor *palette;
}Palette;
```

One game's global palette and one for objects that reference colors in the global palette.

```
PixelColor ShovelKnightColors[] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 255}, 
    {44, 44, 44, 255}, 
    {96, 96, 96, 255}, 
    {200, 192, 192, 255}, 
    {0, 64, 88, 255}, 
    ...
};
Palette GamePalette = {59, ShovelKnightColors};
PixelColor CharacterColors[4];
//This doesn't work
CharacterColors[0] = GamePalette.palette[0];
CharacterColors[1] = GamePalette.palette[17];
CharacterColors[2] = GamePalette.palette[24];
CharacterColors[3] = GamePalette.palette[37];

Palette CharacterPalette = {4, CharactersColors};
```

I'm probably missing a fundamental thing, but I tried any idea I had. As an example:

```
PixelColor CharacterColors[] = {
    GamePalette.palette[0], 
    GamePalette.palette[17], 
    GamePalette.palette[24],
    GamePalette.palette[37]
}
```

All this is outside the main function, just to learn things I don't know about initiation. Please suggest a way to get closest to the initial idea of referencing the same values, because the goal is to create an ESP32 microcontroller project.

Comment: why not:
`PixelColor CharacterColors[4] = {GamePalette.palette[0], GamePalette.palette[17], GamePalette.palette[24], GamePalette.palette[37]};` (notice the 4 which is missing from your example)

Comment: I already tried and I got error: initializer element is not constant. This is before main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code has to do with the fact that you have arrays inside your structs, and arrays need to be initialized.

My suggestion would be to create a `FillPalette()` function that would do the appropriate memory allocation each time:

```
void FillPalette(Palette *p, int size, PixelColor pixelColors[])
{
    p->size = size;
    p->palette = malloc( sizeof(PixelColor) * size );

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        p->palette[ i ].r = pixelColors[ i ].r; 
        p->palette[ i ].g = pixelColors[ i ].g;
        p->palette[ i ].b = pixelColors[ i ].b;
        p->palette[ i ].a = pixelColors[ i ].a;
    }
}
```

Another possibility, in order to avoid the `for` loop, is to use `memcopy` once the array has been initialized.

Anyway, remember to clear the palette when is not going to be used anymore:

```
void ClearPalette(Palette *p)
{
    p->size = 0;
    free( p->palette );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like an elegant solution.